# Book module, taxonomies, url path settings, and breadcrumbs

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri, breadcrumbs, nodes

I am a recent convert to Drupal from Joomla, and while I'm starting to get the hang of it, I just ran into a question that I need some expert advice on.

I'd like to have online versions of a print quarterly newsletter that we produce. It would make sense for each print article to be a separate node, which could then be organized into issues and sections. Ideally, I'd like the url and breadcrumbs to reflect the hierarchy (e.g. mysite.org/newsletter/spring-2012/section-1/lorem-ipsum).

The "Book" module seems perfect for this, but I have no idea how to get the url's and breadcrumbs to work. After some googling, I found somebody somewhere saying that "Book" is somewhat outdated and that anything you could do with "Book" you could do with Taxonomies (besides the obvious differences of presentation, etc. mentioned in one of the other threads on this site). That seemed like the perfect solution for about 30 seconds, until I realized that this would require the content editor (which may not be me) to update the taxonomy terms every time he or she added a newsletter issue. This is possible, but would be a major error-prone hassle.

Any advice or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!